# How can I make my site, play nice with jQuery and Prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, lightbox, lightwindow

I've got a fairly large codebase to work with, and I'm attempting to use a prototype based script. The problem is, I've already got jQuery running, and it's fairly deeply entrenched in the codebase with the $('') functions being used. I'm aware of jQuery's no conflict mode, but it's difficult for me to go back and change all of the code now. Is there an equivalent of no conflict mode for prototype? Failing that, is there an automatic find and replace to replace all of the $() functions to jQuery()?

As a better solution, if anyone knows of a jQuery based [Lightwindow](http://www.p51labs.com/lightwindow/) replacement, I'd be MUCH more grateful. My needs for it are fairly simple, but I've never been able to find one that works right for me. I just want it to work with swf objects, and photos, and not need anchor tags to work. The thing about lightwindow that I like, is I can just do a simple functions like below, to have it work.

```
 $lightbox = "
    myLightWindow.activateWindow({
        href: \"{$this->swfURL}\", 
        title: \"{$this->src->mediaTitle}\", 
        width: $this->width,
        height: $this->height
    });";
  return $lightbox;
```

I tried using http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/ to find a replacement, but it seems to be out of date, and the only one that looked promising was CeeBox, but it was causing all kinds of errors and I believe it is because it's intended for an older version of jQuery.

Well anyways, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not necessarily the ideal solution, but how difficult would it really be to Find>Replace All "$(" with "jQuery(" on your existing script definitions?

Comment: @Nathan Well, to be honest, I'm still not even sure where all of the jQuery code is. It's a large project, and I've only just got started in the codebase, and most of the old devs have left. I do have access to unix utilities that I could use, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that kind of find/replace.

Comment: If you have access to Visual Studio that would allow you to Find and Replace on the 'Entire Solution' or 'Current Project'. If it's a non Visual Studio project, you could always use VS to create a 'Website' from your project's folder structure (won't change any content or create any new files) and then you could access the Find and Replace feature. [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com) is another good tool that does Find and Replace on directories out of the box, but it isn't free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a jquery lightbox clone, check out [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/).  i've used it in a few projects and it is very easy and extensible.  he's also got a few other plugins you should probably look at for modern development, like [prettyLoader](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyloader/).

Comment: prettyPhoto is really solid, but it doesn't play nice in IE9 yet. The dev acknowledged the bug about 2 months ago, so hopefully a patch is forthcoming.

Comment: Taylor, i'm not sure that not playing nice in ie9 should be a real issue.  that's like saying my printer doesn't have drivers for windows 8 yet.

Comment: While I certainly wouldn't preclude it as an option based on IE9 problems, knowledge is power. :)

Comment: @Nathan Taylor, and knowing is half the battle. ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's 95% working for me so far. I'm just having issues with how it embeds the flash. However, I'm confident I can figure it out from here on :) Thanks for the tip!